# cmder ~ alias for user home folder

Tags: user-profile, cmder

Simple question :

I am using cmder and i would like to be able to define `~`(or `~USERID`) as my `%USERPROFILE%` environment variables. I edited `%CMDERROOT%\config\aliases` to add this line : `~=%USERPROFILE%` it does work for `ls` command but not for `cd` for instance.

Is there a better way to have this unix-like user profile aliases ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did but it doesn't work, however I found some answers in project's github issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who would like an answer to that question, it have been addressed in the following github issue :

https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/41

Not a direct answer, but a decent work-around was mentioned in the discussion on that page:

clink, the vendor package that would handle this has a similar issue report marked as "wontfix" So, here's the workaround

> I'm using an AutoHotKey script for that:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
::~::D:/nicolas
#IfWinActive
```

> It replaces automatically ~ with D:/nicolas in ConEmu console (and only ConEmu console)

I have not tried it in a script executed from the command line, but it works from the command line directly, as nicolas suggests.

Comment: I was already using AHK to launch cmder, so this was a very easy addition for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t remember where I got it but add these lines to your profile:

```
function cuserprofile { Set-Location ~ }
Set-Alias ~ cuserprofile -Option AllScope
```

you just hit ~ (enter) and you'll send to your home directory.

PS. I'm using PowerShell in cmder, regards.